# include file to ruby testScript

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

I have multiple ruby test cases for `selenium-webdriver` and all the files are sharing the same user name and password to login to my account. Is there a way to create a global file and include that file in these test cases instead of typing them over and over again, something like  `#include`?

Here is the part of the code that needs to be shared between other test cases:

```
def setup

  @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
  @base_url = "http://localhost:3000/"
  @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
  @verification_errors = []

  @facebook_ID = "xxxxxxxxxx@xxx.xxx"
  @facebook_password = "xxxxxxx"
  @facebook_receiver_friend = "John Smith"

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it.
You could use

```
require 'setup'
```

where `setup.rb` is the common file that has all the setting up variables/functions.

You could also use a YAML file. More information [here](http://yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html). Where all your config attributes can be defined.

Also put this is at the top of the file `$:.unshift '.'` . This is so that your test file can "discover" your setup.rb file which is routable from the home directory.

---

Note - Even though you will save the file as `setup.rb` you will require as only `setup`.

Comment: on my setup.rb, how should I save these variables ? should I put everything in a module ? or "def setup" ........                                        Sorry im new

Comment: Lets start of with `def setup`, and call the function normally from your test file.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer:

```
eval File.open('setup.dat').read
```

This will insert what I have in `setup.dat` as a text wherever I need it.